# Is there something wrong with my caml query for List view?

Tags: sharepoint-addin, caml-query

I want to get all the list items that have status "Waiting Approval" and current user is either Manager1 or Manager2.

```
 <Query>

      <OrderBy>

      </OrderBy>
      <Where>
        <And>
          <Eq>
            <FieldRef Name="Status" />
            <Value Type="Choice">
              Waiting Approval
            </Value>
          </Eq>
          <Or>
            <Eq>
              <FieldRef Name="Manager1ID" />
              <Value Type="Integer">
                <UserID />
              </Value>
            </Eq>

            <Eq>
              <FieldRef Name="Manager2ID" />
              <Value Type="Integer">
                <UserID />
              </Value>
            </Eq>
          </Or>
        </And>
```

At first it was working when only filtering with Manager with an Or operator. Later i just add an additional condition for the Status but it doesn't return any results.

Comment: First try your query validity using any CAML QUERY BUILDER TOOL ex - https://www.biwug.be/resources

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should try:

```
  <Where>
    <Or>
        <And>
            <Eq>
                <FieldRef Name="Status" />
                <Value Type="Choice">
                    Waiting Approval
                </Value>
            </Eq>
            <Eq>
                <FieldRef Name="Manager1ID" />
                <Value Type="Integer">
                <UserID />
                </Value>
            </Eq>
        </And>
        <And>
            <Eq>
                <FieldRef Name="Status" />
                <Value Type="Choice">
                    Waiting Approval
                </Value>
            </Eq>
            <Eq>
                <FieldRef Name="Manager2ID" />
                <Value Type="Integer">
                <UserID />
                </Value>
            </Eq>
        </And>
      </Or>
    </Where>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Still doesn't work . I think it has something to do with the choice field maybe. Should i use the mapping value , so in this case its value 1 for waiting approval , 2 for approved and 3 for rejected

Comment: I found this solution and in text is download for Caml Query builder, so try this way create functional query :)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23372443/sharepoint-caml-query-and-or-operators

Comment: Solution was to have the Value of choice in the same line as the definition of <Value Type="Choice">Waiting Approval</Value>. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

If the Status portion is broken somehow, verify your field name, your field value, and the type of field.

Try the internal field name (if different).

Are you sure it's not "Awaiting Approval" or "Waiting for Approval"?

Is the field type something custom instead of built-in "Choice" field?